Is there any workaround to set drawbox color conditionally?
i want to know if it is possible that setting drawbox color conditionally. With drawtext filter there is option -textfile which gets text value from a local file so that i can get dynamic text value with it.
I want to change box color if certain value is higher than specified condition. The below command is what i'm using for drawing text.
ffmpeg -hide_banner -fflags nobuffer -y -i - \
-filter_complex "drawtext=textfile=max_temp.txt: \
reload=16: \
x=640: y=264: fontsize=36: fontcolor=red, \
drawbox=x=640:y=300:w=640:h=480:color=red" \
...

